# Why can't my code convert the string to int array correctly?

Tags: c++, arrays

I wrote a function that converts a string of numbers separated by a "," to an integer array and print it, so the string:

```
string str = "1,-20,-50,-70,6";
```

becomes:

```
int a[5] = {1,-20,-50,-70,6};
```

everyting seems fine but for the last number where it isn't printed correctly, for the above example the new array is:
1,-50,-20,-70,1999882784

Here is what I have right now:

```
void convert_str_to_int(string str){
    size_t stringLen = str.length(); //find string length
    int arr[stringLen]; //new array to save int values
    string holder = ""; //temporary variable
    int counter = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0;i<stringLen;i++) { 
        if (str[i] != ',')    
            holder = holder+str[i];
        else {
            arr[counter] = atoi(holder.c_str());
            holder = "";
            counter++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0;i<=counter;i++){
           cout<<arr[i]<<endl; //to print the array
    }
}
```

what could be the issue?

Comment: @Somayyah Variable length arrays as this int arr[stringLen]; is not a standard feature of C++.

Comment: `for (int i = 0;i<=counter;i++){` I believe there is an off by 1 bug here.

Comment: where is "6" then

Comment: ***where is "6" then*** It should be in holder after the loop ends. But it was not added to the integer array.

Comment: only one bug actually: not assigning to last element. there's no bug in the loop

Comment: @OP There is no need to write such loops when parsing a comma or space delimited text.  Use `std::istringstream`, as one of the answers points out.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I will give you complete solution, but I am using sstream library. Please read about this on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/

```
std::vector<int> from_string_to_int_vector(const std::string& arr) {
   std::vector<int> numbers;
   std::string token;
   std::istringstream tokenStream(arr);
   while (std::getline(tokenStream, token, ',')) {
      numbers.push_back(atoi(token.c_str()));
   }
   return numbers;
}
```

Comment: You can also use `std::stoi`, but you need to be aware of the exception that could be thrown if the token is not an integer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ofcourse. You should always check documentation for this functions. For instance: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/ it shows that this function (atoi) never throws exception. But it can cause UB. And as you said, stoi will throw exception: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi

Answer (score 1):

This is because you don't have any element at position `counter` in `arr` i.e. `arr[counter]` is a **garbage value**.

Look carefully,

```
//Suppose now counter = 4
arr[counter] = atoi(holder.c_str()); // so this is arr[4]
holder = ""; 
counter++; // now counter is 5
```

It is clear that the index 5 will not be in the range of the size of the array.

So, when you do this

```
// i will have values from 0 to 5 because of i <= counter
for (int i = 0;i<=counter;i++) { 
    cout<<arr[i]<<endl; // when i == counter , it will print garbage value
}
```

You might want to remove the `=` sign and do this instead

```
for (int i = 0;i<counter;i++) { 
    cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
}
```

But still your code will give one element less than what is expected as there is no `,` in the end of the array.
So, after the loop ends you need to do

```
arr[counter] = atoi(holder.c_str());
counter++;
```

Also, you it is wrong to calculate the length of the string and declare an array of that length. Instead do this:

```
int *arr = new int[stringLen];
// if you do this, don't forget to free up the memory by using the following line whenever you no longer require arr
delete arr;
```

Or simply use vector

```
vector<int> arr(stringLen);
```

Below is the entire code

```
void convert_str_to_int(string str){ 
    size_t stringLen = str.length(); 
    vector<int> arr(stringLen);
    string holder = ""; 
    int counter = 0; 
    for (size_t i = 0; i<stringLen; i++) { 
        if (str[i] != ',') {
            holder = holder+str[i]; 
        } else { 
             arr[counter] = atoi(holder.c_str()); 
             holder = ""; 
             counter++; 
        } 
    } 
    arr[counter] = atoi(holder.c_str()); 
    counter++; 
    for (int i = 0;i<=counter;i++){ 
          cout<<arr[i]<<endl; 
    }
}
```

Comment: `int arr[stringLen];` -- Anyone using Visual Studio will be very disappointed when this doesn't compile.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Use `std::vector<int>`.  Your code leaks memory now.

Comment: Is it okay now? @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Yes, it looks ok now.  However as stated in the main comments, better to delegate this to the stream classes rather than writing a loop that could contain bugs.

Comment: Noted. Thank you again :)

Answer (score -1):

For your question,   `for(int i = 0; **i < counter;** ++i)`.

I suggested use some ready functionality of c/c++.

`scanf` , `sscanf`, `fscanf` functions has a formatter `%n` where returns current position. Use it.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string str = "1,-20,-50,-70,6";
    std::vector<int> ints;

    const char* c_str = str.c_str();
    int pos = 0, val;

    // sscanf return number of success read variables, except %n.
    while (sscanf(c_str, "%d,%n", &val, &pos) == 1 ) 
    {
        ints.push_back(val);
        c_str += pos;
    }

    // print result array
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)ints.size(); ++i)
         printf("%d ", ints[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you really like old style c functions? There are a lot good ones, even  performance is sometimes much better than STL. But scanf ist really not in any case better than c++. I would avoid them in c++ context.